# Delete Excel columns and duplicate values from VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, excel

I am trying to create a .Net application to edit a excel file by deleting some columns and keeping the columns which we need and then removing the duplicate values based on the first column which is going to be the Serial no. which should have a check to have 6 digits by default like 2563 should be displayed as 002563.

Please help me..

**EDIT** Code copied from OPs's comment:

```
Public Function GetAllFileContents(ByVal path As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As IList(Of String) 
    Dim contents = New List(Of String) 
    Try 
        Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls") 
        If (files.Length = 0) Then errorMessage = "Please select the files" 
        For Each file In files 
            contents.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.Default)) 
        Next 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        errorMessage = ex.Message 
    End Try 

    Return contents
```

I am trying to create something different by not only letting me do it for excel files but for say txt and csv files along with it. Removing all the values which I dont want and removing the duplicates and then if possible putting a check on the first column of data that the serial number number should have minimum of 6 characters and then The output file should have all the details in Uppercase

Comment: We won't help you by writing your code for you, but we *can* help you to figure things out. So what did you try and where did you get stuck? Can you post your current code?

Comment: Hi Both, I have tried and have done good stuck at the place where I have to delete the columns which I dont need. Please advice

Comment: I was trying to copy the required columns to a new file and then do thde rest of the things. But couldn't do.. :-(

Comment: @Techie, it won't be easy to answer without seeing the code you tried. Can you post the relevant parts of it in your question?

Comment: @Techie, well, I don't think you're going in the right direction, since `xls` files are not text files. You'll probably have to use the [Excel object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx) to manipulate them.

Comment: oh..K can you please advice how can I do it. Please.

Comment: I really need your help please help me i am stuck.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your title? There are rather a lot of VB.Net applications out there and you will get more people coming to this question to help you if you mentioned excel, deleting columns or creating new excel files. It is assumed you mean programmatically, on this site, otherwise it would be a question for SuperUser.

Comment: I am trying to create something different by not only letting me do it for excel files but for say txt and csv files along with it. Removing all the values which I dont want and removing the duplicates and then if possible putting a check on the first column of data that the serial number number should have minimum of 6 characters and then The output file should have all the details in Uppercase.

Comment: @Martin - Hope the description makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this code doesn't need to run on a server or similar and that you have a version of MS Office installed on the machine where it'll run, I'd suggest that the easiest way would be to use Excel Automation. Here's an article that should show you enough to get started: [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982)

If you use that code first, you should be able to figure out how to extract all the data you need, and then you can manipulate it in memory and later just write it back as needed.

Edit: Added more info below:

Look at the line `oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Last Name"` in that sample, that sets a cell to a specific value, just change that to be something like `myVariable = oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value` and you'll get the value for that cell instead. Just loop through getting out the values for all the cells in the column you're interested in. Then just look at this article for info about how to write the values to a text file: [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)

If there are a lot of values, then there's more efficient ways of doing it, but if you get this working first so that you understand this, it would then not be too difficult to make it faster.

Comment: I will try it on.. But just to confirm is there a way by which we can copy a particular column to a new file

Comment: @Techie: Sure, I edited my answer with some more information regarding how you could do this.

Comment: I am trying to create something different by not only letting me do it for excel files but for say txt and csv files along with it. Removing all the values which I dont want and removing the duplicates and then if possible putting a check on the first column of data that the serial number number should have minimum of 6 characters and then The output file should have all the details in Uppercase

Comment: @Techie: Well, you can create an app to handle different kinds of files, but you'll have to use different code for reading an Excel sheet than for reading a text file. However, you could possibly create 3 classes, for example `ParseXls`, `ParseTxt` and `ParseCsv`, all inheriting from the same `Parse` interface, that way you could maybe make the rest of your code work without having to have any knowledge about which type of file it is. Then the rest of your code just creates the right kind of parser, gets out all the values and does what's needed.